# Integration by parts and Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I want to use Integration by parts for general Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals. 
The following theorem can be found in the literature:

**Theorem:** If $F$ and $G$ are right-continuous and non-decreasing functions, we have that:
$$ \int_{(a,b]}G(x)\text{d}F(x)=F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)- \int_{(a,b]}F(x-)\text{d}G(x),$$
where $F(x-)$ is the left limit of $F$ in $x$.

Does the following result hold:

**Theorem:** If $F$ and $G$ are left-continuous and non-decreasing functions, we have that:
$$ \int_{[a,b)}G(x)\text{d}F(x)=F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)- \int_{[a,b)}F(x+)\text{d}G(x),$$
where $F(x+)$ is the right limit of $F$ in $x$.

Is it possible to combine these result. So use integration by parts when $F$ is right cont., $G$ is left cont.?

Answer (score 5):

Variants of the above Lebesgue--Stieltjes partial integral results are given in Theorem 21.67(iv) (it holds for general BV functions, by Remarks 21.68) of Real and Abstract Analysis: A modern treatment of the theory of functions of ...
 E. Hewitt, K. Stromberg [p. 419](https://books.google.fi/books?id=c5zsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=Hewitt%20Stromberg%20%22Real%20and%20abstract%20analysis%22&source=bl&ots=GpiqM382Jn&sig=nD3sMD7ZUM6NmVot3yMEEy0pzFU&hl=fi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit9pf7857JAhUKw3IKHXaADcs4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=integration%20by%20parts&f=false)

They seem to answer your question, though at the cost of having terms like $(F(x+)+F(x-))/2$ in place of $F(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can Compare with the following theorem,

**Theorem**: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions with no common discontinuities on the interval $[a,b]$, and the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $f$ with respect to $g$ exists. Then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $g$ with respect to $f$ exists, and

$$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)df(x) = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dg(x)\,. $$

Comment: But it is not possible get rid of the condition of no common discontinuities?

Comment: I guess that common discontinuities can prevent integrability.

Comment: For Riemann-Stieltjes common discontinuities are a problem. But I would think that for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals, this is condition is not needed. If the common discontinuities are rc, it is no problem.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Every integration by parts theorem I find assumes that $f$ and $g$ are absolutely continuous or something.